# MongoDB - Get Names of All Keys Matching Criteria in a Collection

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

As the title says, I need to retrieve the names of all the keys in my MongoDB collection, BUT I need them split up based on a key/value pair that each document has. Here's my clunky analogy: If you imagine the original collection is a zoo, I need a new collection that contains all the keys Zebras have, all the keys Lions have, and all the keys Giraffes have. The different animal types share many of the same keys, but those keys are meant to be specific to each type of animal (because the user needs to be able to (for example) search for Zebras taller than 3ft and giraffes shorter than 10ft).

Here's a bit of example code that I ran which worked well - it grabbed all the unique keys in my entire collection and threw them into their own collection:

```
db.runCommand({
  "mapreduce" : "MyZoo",
  "map" : function() {
    for (var key in this) { emit(key, null); }
  },
  "reduce" : function(key, stuff) { return null; },
  "out": "MyZoo" + "_keys"
})
```

I'd like a version of this command that would look through the `MyZoo` collection for animals with `"type":"zebra"`, find all the unique keys, and place them in a new collection (`MyZoo_keys`) - then do the same thing for `"type":"lion"` & `"type":"giraffe"`, giving each `"type"` its own array of keys.

Here's the collection I'm starting with:

```
{
    "name": "Zebra1",
    "height": "300",
    "weight": "900",
    "type": "zebra"
    "zebraSpecific1": "somevalue"
},
{
    "name": "Lion1",
    "height": "325",
    "weight": "1200",
    "type": "lion",
},
{
    "name": "Zebra2",
    "height": "500",
    "weight": "2100",
    "type": "zebra",
    "zebraSpecific2": "somevalue"
},
{
    "name": "Giraffe",
    "height": "4800",
    "weight": "2400",
    "type": "giraffe"
    "giraffeSpecific1": "somevalue",
    "giraffeSpecific2": "someothervalue"
}
```

And here's what I'd like the `MyZoo_keys` collection to look like:

```
{
    "zebra": [
        {
            "name": null,
            "height": null,
            "weight": null,
            "type": null,
            "zebraSpecific1": null,
            "zebraSpecific2": null
        }
    ],
    "lion": [
        {
            "name": null,
            "height": null,
            "weight": null,
            "type": null
        }
    ],
    "giraffe": [
        {
            "name": null,
            "height": null,
            "weight": null,
            "type": null,
            "giraffeSpecific1": null,
            "giraffeSpecific2": null
        }
    ]
}
```

That's probably imperfect JSON, but you get the idea...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can modify your code to dump the results in a more readable and organized format.

The `map` function:

- `Emit` the `type` of animal as key, and an array of keys for
  each animal(document). Leave out the `_id` field.

Code:

```
var map = function(){
var keys = [];
Object.keys(this).forEach(function(k){
    if(k != "_id"){
    keys.push(k);
    }
})
emit(this.type,{"keys":keys});
}
```

The `reduce` function:

- For each `type` of animal, consolidate and return the `unique` keys.
- Use an `Object`(`uniqueKeys`) to check for duplicates, this increases the running
  time even if it occupies some memory. The look up is `O(1)`.

Code:

```
var reduce = function(key,values){
    var uniqueKeys = {};
    var result = [];
    values.forEach(function(value){
        value.keys.forEach(function(k){
            if(!uniqueKeys[k]){
                 uniqueKeys[k] = 1;
                 result.push(k);
             }
        })
    })
    return {"keys":result};
}
```

Invoking `Map-Reduce`:

```
db.collection.mapReduce(map,reduce,{out:"t1"});
```

Aggregating the result:

```
db.t1.aggregate([
{$project:{"_id":0,"animal":"$_id","keys":"$value.keys"}}
])
```

Sample o/p:

```
{
        "animal" : "lion",
        "keys" : [
                "name",
                "height",
                "weight",
                "type"
        ]
}
{
        "animal" : "zebra",
        "keys" : [
                "name",
                "height",
                "weight",
                "type",
                "zebraSpecific1",
                "zebraSpecific2"
        ]
}
{
        "animal" : "giraffe",
        "keys" : [
                "name",
                "height",
                "weight",
                "type",
                "giraffeSpecific1",
                "giraffeSpecific2"
        ]
}
```